# How to consume generated *.d.ts files

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am using the following Visual Studio 2017 extension to generate TypeScript interfaces for my MVC-ViewModels: [TypeScript Definition Generator](https://github.com/madskristensen/TypeScriptDefinitionGenerator)

I've tried different ones but they all produce the same output (*.cs.d.ts-File):

```
declare module server {
    interface mycustomtype {
        id: any;
        description: string;
    }
}
```

In my other TypeScript-Files I've tried different variations of using the module/type but all of them produce errors:

```
import { mycustomtype } from '.././../../../../Models/mycustomtype.cs';
```

The above produces the error, that `mycustomtype` is not a module. If I change the output of the Definition Generator to `export module` - the module is recognized but not the type.

Also I've tried using:

```
/// <reference path=".././../../../../Models/mycustomtype.cs" />
```

Above works but intellisense in Visual Studio shows me neither `server.mycustomtype` nor `mycustomtype`.

So my question is: How do I consume these declared modules? In another post I've found that declaring a module without a quote creates an "internal" module. Is that the problem? As there are several TypeScript Definition Generators out there that generate the very same output I guess the problem is not the output - it's me.

Comment: You seem to be referencing the C# files in there... did you mean to reference the `.cs.d.ts` files?

Comment: @Fenton it only seems like it. My generated file is the name of the c# file + ".d.ts". And interestingly enough, when referencing the file, I have to omit the file-extension ".d.ts" as TypeScript seems to add these automatically (so the compiler tells me when I add the extension). So the file that I want to import is called mycustomtype.cs.d.ts.

Answer (score 0):

The d.ts is your definition file, it has nothing to do with module, it is only for intellisense.

So, the .d.ts files required only for telling to TypeScript that the class/interface/enum has been created elsewhere. **By the way, you need to implement it somewhere. Otherwise you can to describe a variable that you get from API request, or describe as in function variable.**

That's why I can't see the need to use it. Instead of I propose just use export and import. In my for of [TypeScript Definition Generator](https://github.com/denis-peshkov/TypeScriptDefinitionGenerator) I realized this possibility.